# increasing number of members in a list causes working list to not work

Tags: r, rstudio

I am making a list with a lot of members. With small number of members, it works fine. However, increasing members beyond a point causes it to not work. I tracked down the point at which it stops working and it's listed below. However, I don't see anything suspicious in the member whose addition causes it to stop working. Does R have a limit on how many members can be added?

Libraries

```
library("RCurl")
library("RJSONIO")
```

Works

```
req = list(
        Inputs = list(


            "input1" = list(
              "ColumnNames" = list("Column 0", "X", "AGE", "FEMALE", "LOS", "NCHRONIC", "RACE", "TOTCHG", "DXCCS_226", "DXCCS_2", "DXCCS_653", "DXCCS_660", "DXCCS_63", "DXCCS_45", "DXCCS_147", "DXCCS_155", "DXCCS_232", "DXCCS_205", "DXCCS_237", "DXCCS_254", "DXCCS_108", "DXCCS_97", "DXCCS_145", "DXCCS_159", "DXCCS_161", "DXCCS_127", "DXCCS_211", "DXCCS_250", "DXCCS_55", "DXCCS_138", "DXCCS_153", "DXCCS_118", "DXCCS_151", "DXCCS_120", "DXCCS_6", "DXCCS_58", "DXCCS_160", "DXCCS_182", "DXCCS_83", "DXCCS_95", "DXCCS_663", "DXCCS_152", "DXCCS_197", "DXCCS_154", "DXCCS_207", "DXCCS_17", "DXCCS_157", "DXCCS_96", "DXCCS_129", "DXCCS_19", "DXCCS_212", "DXCCS_122", "DXCCS_5", "DXCCS_38", "DXCCS_100", "DXCCS_238", "DXCCS_199", "DXCCS_240", "DXCCS_661", "DXCCS_99", "DXCCS_242", "DXCCS_149", "DXCCS_135", "DXCCS_114", "DXCCS_42", "DXCCS_59", "DXCCS_109", "DXCCS_184", "DXCCS_189", "DXCCS_27", "DXCCS_103", "DXCCS_140", "DXCCS_44", "DXCCS_62", "DXCCS_130", "DXCCS_201", "DXCCS_102", "DXCCS_141", "DXCCS_131", "DXCCS_24", "DXCCS_181", "DXCCS_191", "DXCCS_195", "DXCCS_51", "DXCCS_203", "DXCCS_101", "DXCCS_146", "DXCCS_39", "DXCCS_134", "DXCCS_230", "DXCCS_76", "DXCCS_128", "DXCCS_168", "DXCCS_12", "DXCCS_148", "DXCCS_657", "DXCCS_106", "DXCCS_7", "DXCCS_246", "DXCCS_163", "DXCCS_110", "DXCCS_50", "DXCCS_111", "DXCCS_116", "DXCCS_28", "DXCCS_233", "DXCCS_243", "DXCCS_175", "DXCCS_126", "DXCCS_81", "DXCCS_21", "DXCCS_209", "DXCCS_137", "DXCCS_204", "DXCCS_259", "DXCCS_186", "DXCCS_48", "DXCCS_13", "DXCCS_659", "DXCCS_248", "DXCCS_14", "DXCCS_251", "DXCCS_231", "DXCCS_245", "DXCCS_117", "DXCCS_105", "DXCCS_29", "DXCCS_244", "DXCCS_228", "DXCCS_651", "DXCCS_241", "DXCCS_225", "DXCCS_125", "DXCCS_121", "DXCCS_183", "DXCCS_139", "DXCCS_25", "DXCCS_142", "DXCCS_61", "DXCCS_79", "DXCCS_239", "DXCCS_133", "DXCCS_143", "DXCCS_158", "DXCCS_136", "DXCCS_252", "DXCCS_193", "DXCCS_144", "DXCCS_85", "DXCCS_123", "DXCCS_170", "DXCCS_229", "DXCCS_654", "DXCCS_172", "DXCCS_46", "DXCCS_115", "DXCCS_32", "DXCCS_78", "DXCCS_253", "DXCCS_84", "DXCCS_670", "DXCCS_190", "DXCCS_93", "DXCCS_4", "DXCCS_37", "DXCCS_164", "DXCCS_234", "DXCCS_113", "DXCCS_33", "DXCCS_98", "DXCCS_18", "DXCCS_210", "DXCCS_35", "DXCCS_112", "DXCCS_202", "DXCCS_64", "DXCCS_658", "DXCCS_196", "DXCCS_11", "DXCCS_60", "DXCCS_1", "DXCCS_15", "DXCCS_119", "DXCCS_26", "DXCCS_235", "DXCCS_162", "DXCCS_236", "DXCCS_257", "DXCCS_165", "DXCCS_40", "DXCCS_43", "DXCCS_8", "DXCCS_171", "DXCCS_132", "DXCCS_36", "DXCCS_47", "DXCCS_198", "DXCCS_187", "DXCCS_249", "DXCCS_41", "DXCCS_80", "DXCCS_650", "DXCCS_20", "DXCCS_192", "DXCCS_22", "DXCCS_188", "DXCCS_200", "DXCCS_215", "DXCCS_217", "DXCCS_90", "DXCCS_30", "DXCCS_56", "DXCCS_185", "DXCCS_82", "DXCCS_178", "DXCCS_3", "DXCCS_52", "DXCCS_258", "DXCCS_208", "DXCCS_9", "DXCCS_91", "DXCCS_57", "DXCCS_54", "DXCCS_214", "DXCCS_49", "DXCCS_213", "DXCCS_169", "DXCCS_166", "DXCCS_77", "DXCCS_255", "DXCCS_16", "DXCCS_107", "DXCCS_104", "DXCCS_180", "DXCCS_177", "DXCCS_88", "DXCCS_216", "DXCCS_227", "DXCCS_167", "DXCCS_94", "DXCCS_156", "DXCCS_34", "DXCCS_652", "DXCCS_124", "DXCCS_655", "DXCCS_92", "DXCCS_224", "DXCCS_247", "DXCCS_662", "DXCCS_194", "DXCCS_10", "DXCCS_89", "DXCCS_23", "DXCCS_179", "DXCCS_656", "DXCCS_173", "DXCCS_256", "DXCCS_176", "DXCCS_31", "DXCCS_53", "DXCCS_87", "DXCCS_206", "DXCCS_86", "DXCCS_219", "DXCCS_174", "PRCCS_153", "PRCCS_98", "PRCCS_227", "PRCCS_219", "PRCCS_222", "PRCCS_54", "PRCCS_65", "PRCCS_198", "PRCCS_70", "PRCCS_3", "PRCCS_224", "PRCCS_216", "PRCCS_174", "PRCCS_63", "PRCCS_89", "PRCCS_221", "PRCCS_102", "PRCCS_112", "PRCCS_228", "PRCCS_160", "PRCCS_169", "PRCCS_39", "PRCCS_61", "PRCCS_88", "PRCCS_76", "PRCCS_101", "PRCCS_137", "PRCCS_168", "PRCCS_4", "PRCCS_83", "PRCCS_43", "PRCCS_223", "PRCCS_34", "PRCCS_7", "PRCCS_172", "PRCCS_142", "PRCCS_161", "PRCCS_159", "PRCCS_155", "PRCCS_57", "PRCCS_45", "PRCCS_58", "PRCCS_37", "PRCCS_134", "PRCCS_96", "PRCCS_69", "PRCCS_105", "PRCCS_162", "PRCCS_121", "PRCCS_133", "PRCCS_5", "PRCCS_94", "PRCCS_191", "PRCCS_64", "PRCCS_213", "PRCCS_66", "PRCCS_42", "PRCCS_95", "PRCCS_146"),
              "Values" = list("Column 0", "X", "AGE", "FEMALE", "LOS", "NCHRONIC", "RACE", "TOTCHG", "DXCCS_226", "DXCCS_2", "DXCCS_653", "DXCCS_660", "DXCCS_63", "DXCCS_45", "DXCCS_147", "DXCCS_155", "DXCCS_232", "DXCCS_205", "DXCCS_237", "DXCCS_254", "DXCCS_108", "DXCCS_97", "DXCCS_145", "DXCCS_159", "DXCCS_161", "DXCCS_127", "DXCCS_211", "DXCCS_250", "DXCCS_55", "DXCCS_138", "DXCCS_153", "DXCCS_118", "DXCCS_151", "DXCCS_120", "DXCCS_6", "DXCCS_58", "DXCCS_160", "DXCCS_182", "DXCCS_83", "DXCCS_95", "DXCCS_663", "DXCCS_152", "DXCCS_197", "DXCCS_154", "DXCCS_207", "DXCCS_17", "DXCCS_157", "DXCCS_96", "DXCCS_129", "DXCCS_19", "DXCCS_212", "DXCCS_122", "DXCCS_5", "DXCCS_38", "DXCCS_100", "DXCCS_238", "DXCCS_199", "DXCCS_240", "DXCCS_661", "DXCCS_99", "DXCCS_242", "DXCCS_149", "DXCCS_135", "DXCCS_114", "DXCCS_42", "DXCCS_59", "DXCCS_109", "DXCCS_184", "DXCCS_189", "DXCCS_27", "DXCCS_103", "DXCCS_140", "DXCCS_44", "DXCCS_62", "DXCCS_130", "DXCCS_201", "DXCCS_102", "DXCCS_141", "DXCCS_131", "DXCCS_24", "DXCCS_181", "DXCCS_191", "DXCCS_195", "DXCCS_51", "DXCCS_203", "DXCCS_101", "DXCCS_146", "DXCCS_39", "DXCCS_134", "DXCCS_230", "DXCCS_76", "DXCCS_128", "DXCCS_168", "DXCCS_12", "DXCCS_148", "DXCCS_657", "DXCCS_106", "DXCCS_7", "DXCCS_246", "DXCCS_163", "DXCCS_110", "DXCCS_50", "DXCCS_111", "DXCCS_116", "DXCCS_28", "DXCCS_233", "DXCCS_243", "DXCCS_175", "DXCCS_126", "DXCCS_81", "DXCCS_21", "DXCCS_209", "DXCCS_137", "DXCCS_204", "DXCCS_259", "DXCCS_186", "DXCCS_48", "DXCCS_13", "DXCCS_659", "DXCCS_248", "DXCCS_14", "DXCCS_251", "DXCCS_231", "DXCCS_245", "DXCCS_117", "DXCCS_105", "DXCCS_29", "DXCCS_244", "DXCCS_228", "DXCCS_651", "DXCCS_241", "DXCCS_225", "DXCCS_125", "DXCCS_121", "DXCCS_183", "DXCCS_139", "DXCCS_25", "DXCCS_142", "DXCCS_61", "DXCCS_79", "DXCCS_239", "DXCCS_133", "DXCCS_143", "DXCCS_158", "DXCCS_136", "DXCCS_252", "DXCCS_193", "DXCCS_144", "DXCCS_85", "DXCCS_123", "DXCCS_170", "DXCCS_229", "DXCCS_654", "DXCCS_172", "DXCCS_46", "DXCCS_115", "DXCCS_32", "DXCCS_78", "DXCCS_253", "DXCCS_84", "DXCCS_670", "DXCCS_190", "DXCCS_93", "DXCCS_4", "DXCCS_37", "DXCCS_164", "DXCCS_234", "DXCCS_113", "DXCCS_33", "DXCCS_98", "DXCCS_18", "DXCCS_210", "DXCCS_35", "DXCCS_112", "DXCCS_202", "DXCCS_64", "DXCCS_658", "DXCCS_196", "DXCCS_11", "DXCCS_60", "DXCCS_1", "DXCCS_15", "DXCCS_119", "DXCCS_26", "DXCCS_235", "DXCCS_162", "DXCCS_236", "DXCCS_257", "DXCCS_165", "DXCCS_40", "DXCCS_43", "DXCCS_8", "DXCCS_171", "DXCCS_132", "DXCCS_36", "DXCCS_47", "DXCCS_198", "DXCCS_187", "DXCCS_249", "DXCCS_41", "DXCCS_80", "DXCCS_650", "DXCCS_20", "DXCCS_192", "DXCCS_22", "DXCCS_188", "DXCCS_200", "DXCCS_215", "DXCCS_217", "DXCCS_90", "DXCCS_30", "DXCCS_56", "DXCCS_185", "DXCCS_82", "DXCCS_178", "DXCCS_3", "DXCCS_52", "DXCCS_258", "DXCCS_208", "DXCCS_9", "DXCCS_91", "DXCCS_57", "DXCCS_54", "DXCCS_214", "DXCCS_49", "DXCCS_213", "DXCCS_169", "DXCCS_166", "DXCCS_77", "DXCCS_255", "DXCCS_16", "DXCCS_107", "DXCCS_104", "DXCCS_180", "DXCCS_177", "DXCCS_88", "DXCCS_216", "DXCCS_227", "DXCCS_167", "DXCCS_94", "DXCCS_156", "DXCCS_34", "DXCCS_652", "DXCCS_124", "DXCCS_655", "DXCCS_92", "DXCCS_224", "DXCCS_247", "DXCCS_662", "DXCCS_194", "DXCCS_10", "DXCCS_89", "DXCCS_23", "DXCCS_179", "DXCCS_656", "DXCCS_173", "DXCCS_256", "DXCCS_176", "DXCCS_31", "DXCCS_53", "DXCCS_87", "DXCCS_206", "DXCCS_86", "DXCCS_219", "DXCCS_174", "PRCCS_153", "PRCCS_98", "PRCCS_227", "PRCCS_219", "PRCCS_222", "PRCCS_54", "PRCCS_65", "PRCCS_198", "PRCCS_70", "PRCCS_3", "PRCCS_224", "PRCCS_216", "PRCCS_174", "PRCCS_63", "PRCCS_89", "PRCCS_221", "PRCCS_102", "PRCCS_112", "PRCCS_228", "PRCCS_160", "PRCCS_169", "PRCCS_39", "PRCCS_61", "PRCCS_88", "PRCCS_76", "PRCCS_101", "PRCCS_137", "PRCCS_168", "PRCCS_4", "PRCCS_83", "PRCCS_43", "PRCCS_223", "PRCCS_34", "PRCCS_7", "PRCCS_172", "PRCCS_142", "PRCCS_161", "PRCCS_159", "PRCCS_155", "PRCCS_57", "PRCCS_45", "PRCCS_58", "PRCCS_37", "PRCCS_134", "PRCCS_96", "PRCCS_69", "PRCCS_105", "PRCCS_162", "PRCCS_121", "PRCCS_133", "PRCCS_5", "PRCCS_94", "PRCCS_191", "PRCCS_64", "PRCCS_213", "PRCCS_66", "PRCCS_42", "PRCCS_95", "PRCCS_146")

                            )                
                      ),
        GlobalParameters = fromJSON('{}')
          )
```

Gives an error

```
req = list(
        Inputs = list(


            "input1" = list(
              "ColumnNames" = list("Column 0", "X", "AGE", "FEMALE", "LOS", "NCHRONIC", "RACE", "TOTCHG", "DXCCS_226", "DXCCS_2", "DXCCS_653", "DXCCS_660", "DXCCS_63", "DXCCS_45", "DXCCS_147", "DXCCS_155", "DXCCS_232", "DXCCS_205", "DXCCS_237", "DXCCS_254", "DXCCS_108", "DXCCS_97", "DXCCS_145", "DXCCS_159", "DXCCS_161", "DXCCS_127", "DXCCS_211", "DXCCS_250", "DXCCS_55", "DXCCS_138", "DXCCS_153", "DXCCS_118", "DXCCS_151", "DXCCS_120", "DXCCS_6", "DXCCS_58", "DXCCS_160", "DXCCS_182", "DXCCS_83", "DXCCS_95", "DXCCS_663", "DXCCS_152", "DXCCS_197", "DXCCS_154", "DXCCS_207", "DXCCS_17", "DXCCS_157", "DXCCS_96", "DXCCS_129", "DXCCS_19", "DXCCS_212", "DXCCS_122", "DXCCS_5", "DXCCS_38", "DXCCS_100", "DXCCS_238", "DXCCS_199", "DXCCS_240", "DXCCS_661", "DXCCS_99", "DXCCS_242", "DXCCS_149", "DXCCS_135", "DXCCS_114", "DXCCS_42", "DXCCS_59", "DXCCS_109", "DXCCS_184", "DXCCS_189", "DXCCS_27", "DXCCS_103", "DXCCS_140", "DXCCS_44", "DXCCS_62", "DXCCS_130", "DXCCS_201", "DXCCS_102", "DXCCS_141", "DXCCS_131", "DXCCS_24", "DXCCS_181", "DXCCS_191", "DXCCS_195", "DXCCS_51", "DXCCS_203", "DXCCS_101", "DXCCS_146", "DXCCS_39", "DXCCS_134", "DXCCS_230", "DXCCS_76", "DXCCS_128", "DXCCS_168", "DXCCS_12", "DXCCS_148", "DXCCS_657", "DXCCS_106", "DXCCS_7", "DXCCS_246", "DXCCS_163", "DXCCS_110", "DXCCS_50", "DXCCS_111", "DXCCS_116", "DXCCS_28", "DXCCS_233", "DXCCS_243", "DXCCS_175", "DXCCS_126", "DXCCS_81", "DXCCS_21", "DXCCS_209", "DXCCS_137", "DXCCS_204", "DXCCS_259", "DXCCS_186", "DXCCS_48", "DXCCS_13", "DXCCS_659", "DXCCS_248", "DXCCS_14", "DXCCS_251", "DXCCS_231", "DXCCS_245", "DXCCS_117", "DXCCS_105", "DXCCS_29", "DXCCS_244", "DXCCS_228", "DXCCS_651", "DXCCS_241", "DXCCS_225", "DXCCS_125", "DXCCS_121", "DXCCS_183", "DXCCS_139", "DXCCS_25", "DXCCS_142", "DXCCS_61", "DXCCS_79", "DXCCS_239", "DXCCS_133", "DXCCS_143", "DXCCS_158", "DXCCS_136", "DXCCS_252", "DXCCS_193", "DXCCS_144", "DXCCS_85", "DXCCS_123", "DXCCS_170", "DXCCS_229", "DXCCS_654", "DXCCS_172", "DXCCS_46", "DXCCS_115", "DXCCS_32", "DXCCS_78", "DXCCS_253", "DXCCS_84", "DXCCS_670", "DXCCS_190", "DXCCS_93", "DXCCS_4", "DXCCS_37", "DXCCS_164", "DXCCS_234", "DXCCS_113", "DXCCS_33", "DXCCS_98", "DXCCS_18", "DXCCS_210", "DXCCS_35", "DXCCS_112", "DXCCS_202", "DXCCS_64", "DXCCS_658", "DXCCS_196", "DXCCS_11", "DXCCS_60", "DXCCS_1", "DXCCS_15", "DXCCS_119", "DXCCS_26", "DXCCS_235", "DXCCS_162", "DXCCS_236", "DXCCS_257", "DXCCS_165", "DXCCS_40", "DXCCS_43", "DXCCS_8", "DXCCS_171", "DXCCS_132", "DXCCS_36", "DXCCS_47", "DXCCS_198", "DXCCS_187", "DXCCS_249", "DXCCS_41", "DXCCS_80", "DXCCS_650", "DXCCS_20", "DXCCS_192", "DXCCS_22", "DXCCS_188", "DXCCS_200", "DXCCS_215", "DXCCS_217", "DXCCS_90", "DXCCS_30", "DXCCS_56", "DXCCS_185", "DXCCS_82", "DXCCS_178", "DXCCS_3", "DXCCS_52", "DXCCS_258", "DXCCS_208", "DXCCS_9", "DXCCS_91", "DXCCS_57", "DXCCS_54", "DXCCS_214", "DXCCS_49", "DXCCS_213", "DXCCS_169", "DXCCS_166", "DXCCS_77", "DXCCS_255", "DXCCS_16", "DXCCS_107", "DXCCS_104", "DXCCS_180", "DXCCS_177", "DXCCS_88", "DXCCS_216", "DXCCS_227", "DXCCS_167", "DXCCS_94", "DXCCS_156", "DXCCS_34", "DXCCS_652", "DXCCS_124", "DXCCS_655", "DXCCS_92", "DXCCS_224", "DXCCS_247", "DXCCS_662", "DXCCS_194", "DXCCS_10", "DXCCS_89", "DXCCS_23", "DXCCS_179", "DXCCS_656", "DXCCS_173", "DXCCS_256", "DXCCS_176", "DXCCS_31", "DXCCS_53", "DXCCS_87", "DXCCS_206", "DXCCS_86", "DXCCS_219", "DXCCS_174", "PRCCS_153", "PRCCS_98", "PRCCS_227", "PRCCS_219", "PRCCS_222", "PRCCS_54", "PRCCS_65", "PRCCS_198", "PRCCS_70", "PRCCS_3", "PRCCS_224", "PRCCS_216", "PRCCS_174", "PRCCS_63", "PRCCS_89", "PRCCS_221", "PRCCS_102", "PRCCS_112", "PRCCS_228", "PRCCS_160", "PRCCS_169", "PRCCS_39", "PRCCS_61", "PRCCS_88", "PRCCS_76", "PRCCS_101", "PRCCS_137", "PRCCS_168", "PRCCS_4", "PRCCS_83", "PRCCS_43", "PRCCS_223", "PRCCS_34", "PRCCS_7", "PRCCS_172", "PRCCS_142", "PRCCS_161", "PRCCS_159", "PRCCS_155", "PRCCS_57", "PRCCS_45", "PRCCS_58", "PRCCS_37", "PRCCS_134", "PRCCS_96", "PRCCS_69", "PRCCS_105", "PRCCS_162", "PRCCS_121", "PRCCS_133", "PRCCS_5", "PRCCS_94", "PRCCS_191", "PRCCS_64", "PRCCS_213", "PRCCS_66", "PRCCS_42", "PRCCS_95", "PRCCS_146", "PRCCS_47"),
              "Values" = list("Column 0", "X", "AGE", "FEMALE", "LOS", "NCHRONIC", "RACE", "TOTCHG", "DXCCS_226", "DXCCS_2", "DXCCS_653", "DXCCS_660", "DXCCS_63", "DXCCS_45", "DXCCS_147", "DXCCS_155", "DXCCS_232", "DXCCS_205", "DXCCS_237", "DXCCS_254", "DXCCS_108", "DXCCS_97", "DXCCS_145", "DXCCS_159", "DXCCS_161", "DXCCS_127", "DXCCS_211", "DXCCS_250", "DXCCS_55", "DXCCS_138", "DXCCS_153", "DXCCS_118", "DXCCS_151", "DXCCS_120", "DXCCS_6", "DXCCS_58", "DXCCS_160", "DXCCS_182", "DXCCS_83", "DXCCS_95", "DXCCS_663", "DXCCS_152", "DXCCS_197", "DXCCS_154", "DXCCS_207", "DXCCS_17", "DXCCS_157", "DXCCS_96", "DXCCS_129", "DXCCS_19", "DXCCS_212", "DXCCS_122", "DXCCS_5", "DXCCS_38", "DXCCS_100", "DXCCS_238", "DXCCS_199", "DXCCS_240", "DXCCS_661", "DXCCS_99", "DXCCS_242", "DXCCS_149", "DXCCS_135", "DXCCS_114", "DXCCS_42", "DXCCS_59", "DXCCS_109", "DXCCS_184", "DXCCS_189", "DXCCS_27", "DXCCS_103", "DXCCS_140", "DXCCS_44", "DXCCS_62", "DXCCS_130", "DXCCS_201", "DXCCS_102", "DXCCS_141", "DXCCS_131", "DXCCS_24", "DXCCS_181", "DXCCS_191", "DXCCS_195", "DXCCS_51", "DXCCS_203", "DXCCS_101", "DXCCS_146", "DXCCS_39", "DXCCS_134", "DXCCS_230", "DXCCS_76", "DXCCS_128", "DXCCS_168", "DXCCS_12", "DXCCS_148", "DXCCS_657", "DXCCS_106", "DXCCS_7", "DXCCS_246", "DXCCS_163", "DXCCS_110", "DXCCS_50", "DXCCS_111", "DXCCS_116", "DXCCS_28", "DXCCS_233", "DXCCS_243", "DXCCS_175", "DXCCS_126", "DXCCS_81", "DXCCS_21", "DXCCS_209", "DXCCS_137", "DXCCS_204", "DXCCS_259", "DXCCS_186", "DXCCS_48", "DXCCS_13", "DXCCS_659", "DXCCS_248", "DXCCS_14", "DXCCS_251", "DXCCS_231", "DXCCS_245", "DXCCS_117", "DXCCS_105", "DXCCS_29", "DXCCS_244", "DXCCS_228", "DXCCS_651", "DXCCS_241", "DXCCS_225", "DXCCS_125", "DXCCS_121", "DXCCS_183", "DXCCS_139", "DXCCS_25", "DXCCS_142", "DXCCS_61", "DXCCS_79", "DXCCS_239", "DXCCS_133", "DXCCS_143", "DXCCS_158", "DXCCS_136", "DXCCS_252", "DXCCS_193", "DXCCS_144", "DXCCS_85", "DXCCS_123", "DXCCS_170", "DXCCS_229", "DXCCS_654", "DXCCS_172", "DXCCS_46", "DXCCS_115", "DXCCS_32", "DXCCS_78", "DXCCS_253", "DXCCS_84", "DXCCS_670", "DXCCS_190", "DXCCS_93", "DXCCS_4", "DXCCS_37", "DXCCS_164", "DXCCS_234", "DXCCS_113", "DXCCS_33", "DXCCS_98", "DXCCS_18", "DXCCS_210", "DXCCS_35", "DXCCS_112", "DXCCS_202", "DXCCS_64", "DXCCS_658", "DXCCS_196", "DXCCS_11", "DXCCS_60", "DXCCS_1", "DXCCS_15", "DXCCS_119", "DXCCS_26", "DXCCS_235", "DXCCS_162", "DXCCS_236", "DXCCS_257", "DXCCS_165", "DXCCS_40", "DXCCS_43", "DXCCS_8", "DXCCS_171", "DXCCS_132", "DXCCS_36", "DXCCS_47", "DXCCS_198", "DXCCS_187", "DXCCS_249", "DXCCS_41", "DXCCS_80", "DXCCS_650", "DXCCS_20", "DXCCS_192", "DXCCS_22", "DXCCS_188", "DXCCS_200", "DXCCS_215", "DXCCS_217", "DXCCS_90", "DXCCS_30", "DXCCS_56", "DXCCS_185", "DXCCS_82", "DXCCS_178", "DXCCS_3", "DXCCS_52", "DXCCS_258", "DXCCS_208", "DXCCS_9", "DXCCS_91", "DXCCS_57", "DXCCS_54", "DXCCS_214", "DXCCS_49", "DXCCS_213", "DXCCS_169", "DXCCS_166", "DXCCS_77", "DXCCS_255", "DXCCS_16", "DXCCS_107", "DXCCS_104", "DXCCS_180", "DXCCS_177", "DXCCS_88", "DXCCS_216", "DXCCS_227", "DXCCS_167", "DXCCS_94", "DXCCS_156", "DXCCS_34", "DXCCS_652", "DXCCS_124", "DXCCS_655", "DXCCS_92", "DXCCS_224", "DXCCS_247", "DXCCS_662", "DXCCS_194", "DXCCS_10", "DXCCS_89", "DXCCS_23", "DXCCS_179", "DXCCS_656", "DXCCS_173", "DXCCS_256", "DXCCS_176", "DXCCS_31", "DXCCS_53", "DXCCS_87", "DXCCS_206", "DXCCS_86", "DXCCS_219", "DXCCS_174", "PRCCS_153", "PRCCS_98", "PRCCS_227", "PRCCS_219", "PRCCS_222", "PRCCS_54", "PRCCS_65", "PRCCS_198", "PRCCS_70", "PRCCS_3", "PRCCS_224", "PRCCS_216", "PRCCS_174", "PRCCS_63", "PRCCS_89", "PRCCS_221", "PRCCS_102", "PRCCS_112", "PRCCS_228", "PRCCS_160", "PRCCS_169", "PRCCS_39", "PRCCS_61", "PRCCS_88", "PRCCS_76", "PRCCS_101", "PRCCS_137", "PRCCS_168", "PRCCS_4", "PRCCS_83", "PRCCS_43", "PRCCS_223", "PRCCS_34", "PRCCS_7", "PRCCS_172", "PRCCS_142", "PRCCS_161", "PRCCS_159", "PRCCS_155", "PRCCS_57", "PRCCS_45", "PRCCS_58", "PRCCS_37", "PRCCS_134", "PRCCS_96", "PRCCS_69", "PRCCS_105", "PRCCS_162", "PRCCS_121", "PRCCS_133", "PRCCS_5", "PRCCS_94", "PRCCS_191", "PRCCS_64", "PRCCS_213", "PRCCS_66", "PRCCS_42", "PRCCS_95", "PRCCS_146", "PRCCS_47")

                            )                
                      ),
        GlobalParameters = fromJSON('{}')
          )
```

Cursor just gives a '+' which means it's expecting more input

```
req = list(
        Inputs = list(


            "input1" = list(
              "ColumnNames" = list("Column 0", "X", "AGE", "FEMALE", "LOS", "NCHRONIC", "RACE", "TOTCHG", "DXCCS_226", "DXCCS_2", "DXCCS_653", "DXCCS_660", "DXCCS_63", "DXCCS_45", "DXCCS_147", "DXCCS_155", "DXCCS_232", "DXCCS_205", "DXCCS_237", "DXCCS_254", "DXCCS_108", "DXCCS_97", "DXCCS_145", "DXCCS_159", "DXCCS_161", "DXCCS_127", "DXCCS_211", "DXCCS_250", "DXCCS_55", "DXCCS_138", "DXCCS_153", "DXCCS_118", "DXCCS_151", "DXCCS_120", "DXCCS_6", "DXCCS_58", "DXCCS_160", "DXCCS_182", "DXCCS_83", "DXCCS_95", "DXCCS_663", "DXCCS_152", "DXCCS_197", "DXCCS_154", "DXCCS_207", "DXCCS_17", "DXCCS_157", "DXCCS_96", "DXCCS_129", "DXCCS_19", "DXCCS_212", "DXCCS_122", "DXCCS_5", "DXCCS_38", "DXCCS_100", "DXCCS_238", "DXCCS_199", "DXCCS_240", "DXCCS_661", "DXCCS_99", "DXCCS_242", "DXCCS_149", "DXCCS_135", "DXCCS_114", "DXCCS_42", "DXCCS_59", "DXCCS_109", "DXCCS_184", "DXCCS_189", "DXCCS_27", "DXCCS_103", "DXCCS_140", "DXCCS_44", "DXCCS_62", "DXCCS_130", "DXCCS_201", "DXCCS_102", "DXCCS_141", "DXCCS_131", "DXCCS_24", "DXCCS_181", "DXCCS_191", "DXCCS_195", "DXCCS_51", "DXCCS_203", "DXCCS_101", "DXCCS_146", "DXCCS_39", "DXCCS_134", "DXCCS_230", "DXCCS_76", "DXCCS_128", "DXCCS_168", "DXCCS_12", "DXCCS_148", "DXCCS_657", "DXCCS_106", "DXCCS_7", "DXCCS_246", "DXCCS_163", "DXCCS_110", "DXCCS_50", "DXCCS_111", "DXCCS_116", "DXCCS_28", "DXCCS_233", "DXCCS_243", "DXCCS_175", "DXCCS_126", "DXCCS_81", "DXCCS_21", "DXCCS_209", "DXCCS_137", "DXCCS_204", "DXCCS_259", "DXCCS_186", "DXCCS_48", "DXCCS_13", "DXCCS_659", "DXCCS_248", "DXCCS_14", "DXCCS_251", "DXCCS_231", "DXCCS_245", "DXCCS_117", "DXCCS_105", "DXCCS_29", "DXCCS_244", "DXCCS_228", "DXCCS_651", "DXCCS_241", "DXCCS_225", "DXCCS_125", "DXCCS_121", "DXCCS_183", "DXCCS_139", "DXCCS_25", "DXCCS_142", "DXCCS_61", "DXCCS_79", "DXCCS_239", "DXCCS_133", "DXCCS_143", "DXCCS_158", "DXCCS_136", "DXCCS_252", "DXCCS_193", "DXCCS_144", "DXCCS_85", "DXCCS_123", "DXCCS_170", "DXCCS_229", "DXCCS_654", "DXCCS_172", "DXCCS_46", "DXCCS_115", "DXCCS_32", "DXCCS_78", "DXCCS_253", "DXCCS_84", "DXCCS_670", "DXCCS_190", "DXCCS_93", "DXCCS_4", "DXCCS_37", "DXCCS_164", "DXCCS_234", "DXCCS_113", "DXCCS_33", "DXCCS_98", "DXCCS_18", "DXCCS_210", "DXCCS_35", "DXCCS_112", "DXCCS_202", "DXCCS_64", "DXCCS_658", "DXCCS_196", "DXCCS_11", "DXCCS_60", "DXCCS_1", "DXCCS_15", "DXCCS_119", "DXCCS_26", "DXCCS_235", "DXCCS_162", "DXCCS_236", "DXCCS_257", "DXCCS_165", "DXCCS_40", "DXCCS_43", "DXCCS_8", "DXCCS_171", "DXCCS_132", "DXCCS_36", "DXCCS_47", "DXCCS_198", "DXCCS_187", "DXCCS_249", "DXCCS_41", "DXCCS_80", "DXCCS_650", "DXCCS_20", "DXCCS_192", "DXCCS_22", "DXCCS_188", "DXCCS_200", "DXCCS_215", "DXCCS_217", "DXCCS_90", "DXCCS_30", "DXCCS_56", "DXCCS_185", "DXCCS_82", "DXCCS_178", "DXCCS_3", "DXCCS_52", "DXCCS_258", "DXCCS_208", "DXCCS_9", "DXCCS_91", "DXCCS_57", "DXCCS_54", "DXCCS_214", "DXCCS_49", "DXCCS_213", "DXCCS_169", "DXCCS_166", "DXCCS_77", "DXCCS_255", "DXCCS_16", "DXCCS_107", "DXCCS_104", "DXCCS_180", "DXCCS_177", "DXCCS_88", "DXCCS_216", "DXCCS_227", "DXCCS_167", "DXCCS_94", "DXCCS_156", "DXCCS_34", "DXCCS_652", "DXCCS_124", "DXCCS_655", "DXCCS_92", "DXCCS_224", "DXCCS_247", "DXCCS_662", "DXCCS_194", "DXCCS_10", "DXCCS_89", "DXCCS_23", "DXCCS_179", "DXCCS_656", "DXCCS_173", "DXCCS_256", "DXCCS_176", "DXCCS_31", "DXCCS_53", "DXCCS_87", "DXCCS_206", "DXCCS_86", "DXCCS_219", "DXCCS_174", "PRCCS_153", "PRCCS_98", "PRCCS_227", "PRCCS_219", "PRCCS_222", "PRCCS_54", "PRCCS_65", "PRCCS_198", "PRCCS_70", "PRCCS_3", "PRCCS_224", "PRCCS_216", "PRCCS_174", "PRCCS_63", "PRCCS_89", "PRCCS_221", "PRCCS_102", "PRCCS_112", "PRCCS_228", "PRCCS_160", "PRCCS_169", "PRCCS_39", "PRCCS_61", "PRCCS_88", "PRCCS_76", "PRCCS_101", "PRCCS_137", "PRCCS_168", "PRCCS_4", "PRCCS_83", "PRCCS_43", "PRCCS_223", "PRCCS_34", "PRCCS_7", "PRCCS_172", "PRCCS_142", "PRCCS_161", "PRCCS_159", "PRCCS_155", "PRCCS_57", "PRCCS_45", "PRCCS_58", "PRCCS_37", "PRCCS_134", "PRCCS_96", "PRCCS_69", "PRCCS_105", "PRCCS_162", "PRCCS_121", "PRCCS_133", "PRCCS_5", "PRCCS_94", "PRCCS_191", "PRCCS_64", "PRCCS_213", "PRCCS_66", "PRCCS_42", "PRCCS_95", "PRCCS_146", "PRCCS_47", "PRCCS_78"),
              "Values" = list("Column 0", "X", "AGE", "FEMALE", "LOS", "NCHRONIC", "RACE", "TOTCHG", "DXCCS_226", "DXCCS_2", "DXCCS_653", "DXCCS_660", "DXCCS_63", "DXCCS_45", "DXCCS_147", "DXCCS_155", "DXCCS_232", "DXCCS_205", "DXCCS_237", "DXCCS_254", "DXCCS_108", "DXCCS_97", "DXCCS_145", "DXCCS_159", "DXCCS_161", "DXCCS_127", "DXCCS_211", "DXCCS_250", "DXCCS_55", "DXCCS_138", "DXCCS_153", "DXCCS_118", "DXCCS_151", "DXCCS_120", "DXCCS_6", "DXCCS_58", "DXCCS_160", "DXCCS_182", "DXCCS_83", "DXCCS_95", "DXCCS_663", "DXCCS_152", "DXCCS_197", "DXCCS_154", "DXCCS_207", "DXCCS_17", "DXCCS_157", "DXCCS_96", "DXCCS_129", "DXCCS_19", "DXCCS_212", "DXCCS_122", "DXCCS_5", "DXCCS_38", "DXCCS_100", "DXCCS_238", "DXCCS_199", "DXCCS_240", "DXCCS_661", "DXCCS_99", "DXCCS_242", "DXCCS_149", "DXCCS_135", "DXCCS_114", "DXCCS_42", "DXCCS_59", "DXCCS_109", "DXCCS_184", "DXCCS_189", "DXCCS_27", "DXCCS_103", "DXCCS_140", "DXCCS_44", "DXCCS_62", "DXCCS_130", "DXCCS_201", "DXCCS_102", "DXCCS_141", "DXCCS_131", "DXCCS_24", "DXCCS_181", "DXCCS_191", "DXCCS_195", "DXCCS_51", "DXCCS_203", "DXCCS_101", "DXCCS_146", "DXCCS_39", "DXCCS_134", "DXCCS_230", "DXCCS_76", "DXCCS_128", "DXCCS_168", "DXCCS_12", "DXCCS_148", "DXCCS_657", "DXCCS_106", "DXCCS_7", "DXCCS_246", "DXCCS_163", "DXCCS_110", "DXCCS_50", "DXCCS_111", "DXCCS_116", "DXCCS_28", "DXCCS_233", "DXCCS_243", "DXCCS_175", "DXCCS_126", "DXCCS_81", "DXCCS_21", "DXCCS_209", "DXCCS_137", "DXCCS_204", "DXCCS_259", "DXCCS_186", "DXCCS_48", "DXCCS_13", "DXCCS_659", "DXCCS_248", "DXCCS_14", "DXCCS_251", "DXCCS_231", "DXCCS_245", "DXCCS_117", "DXCCS_105", "DXCCS_29", "DXCCS_244", "DXCCS_228", "DXCCS_651", "DXCCS_241", "DXCCS_225", "DXCCS_125", "DXCCS_121", "DXCCS_183", "DXCCS_139", "DXCCS_25", "DXCCS_142", "DXCCS_61", "DXCCS_79", "DXCCS_239", "DXCCS_133", "DXCCS_143", "DXCCS_158", "DXCCS_136", "DXCCS_252", "DXCCS_193", "DXCCS_144", "DXCCS_85", "DXCCS_123", "DXCCS_170", "DXCCS_229", "DXCCS_654", "DXCCS_172", "DXCCS_46", "DXCCS_115", "DXCCS_32", "DXCCS_78", "DXCCS_253", "DXCCS_84", "DXCCS_670", "DXCCS_190", "DXCCS_93", "DXCCS_4", "DXCCS_37", "DXCCS_164", "DXCCS_234", "DXCCS_113", "DXCCS_33", "DXCCS_98", "DXCCS_18", "DXCCS_210", "DXCCS_35", "DXCCS_112", "DXCCS_202", "DXCCS_64", "DXCCS_658", "DXCCS_196", "DXCCS_11", "DXCCS_60", "DXCCS_1", "DXCCS_15", "DXCCS_119", "DXCCS_26", "DXCCS_235", "DXCCS_162", "DXCCS_236", "DXCCS_257", "DXCCS_165", "DXCCS_40", "DXCCS_43", "DXCCS_8", "DXCCS_171", "DXCCS_132", "DXCCS_36", "DXCCS_47", "DXCCS_198", "DXCCS_187", "DXCCS_249", "DXCCS_41", "DXCCS_80", "DXCCS_650", "DXCCS_20", "DXCCS_192", "DXCCS_22", "DXCCS_188", "DXCCS_200", "DXCCS_215", "DXCCS_217", "DXCCS_90", "DXCCS_30", "DXCCS_56", "DXCCS_185", "DXCCS_82", "DXCCS_178", "DXCCS_3", "DXCCS_52", "DXCCS_258", "DXCCS_208", "DXCCS_9", "DXCCS_91", "DXCCS_57", "DXCCS_54", "DXCCS_214", "DXCCS_49", "DXCCS_213", "DXCCS_169", "DXCCS_166", "DXCCS_77", "DXCCS_255", "DXCCS_16", "DXCCS_107", "DXCCS_104", "DXCCS_180", "DXCCS_177", "DXCCS_88", "DXCCS_216", "DXCCS_227", "DXCCS_167", "DXCCS_94", "DXCCS_156", "DXCCS_34", "DXCCS_652", "DXCCS_124", "DXCCS_655", "DXCCS_92", "DXCCS_224", "DXCCS_247", "DXCCS_662", "DXCCS_194", "DXCCS_10", "DXCCS_89", "DXCCS_23", "DXCCS_179", "DXCCS_656", "DXCCS_173", "DXCCS_256", "DXCCS_176", "DXCCS_31", "DXCCS_53", "DXCCS_87", "DXCCS_206", "DXCCS_86", "DXCCS_219", "DXCCS_174", "PRCCS_153", "PRCCS_98", "PRCCS_227", "PRCCS_219", "PRCCS_222", "PRCCS_54", "PRCCS_65", "PRCCS_198", "PRCCS_70", "PRCCS_3", "PRCCS_224", "PRCCS_216", "PRCCS_174", "PRCCS_63", "PRCCS_89", "PRCCS_221", "PRCCS_102", "PRCCS_112", "PRCCS_228", "PRCCS_160", "PRCCS_169", "PRCCS_39", "PRCCS_61", "PRCCS_88", "PRCCS_76", "PRCCS_101", "PRCCS_137", "PRCCS_168", "PRCCS_4", "PRCCS_83", "PRCCS_43", "PRCCS_223", "PRCCS_34", "PRCCS_7", "PRCCS_172", "PRCCS_142", "PRCCS_161", "PRCCS_159", "PRCCS_155", "PRCCS_57", "PRCCS_45", "PRCCS_58", "PRCCS_37", "PRCCS_134", "PRCCS_96", "PRCCS_69", "PRCCS_105", "PRCCS_162", "PRCCS_121", "PRCCS_133", "PRCCS_5", "PRCCS_94", "PRCCS_191", "PRCCS_64", "PRCCS_213", "PRCCS_66", "PRCCS_42", "PRCCS_95", "PRCCS_146", "PRCCS_47", "PRCCS_78")

                            )                
                      ),
        GlobalParameters = fromJSON('{}')
          )
```

Comment: `Error: could not find function "fromJSON"`

Comment: Did you load an appropriate library? i.e. library(rjson)? I don't get an error with your first or second chunk when doing so.

Comment: @Pascal, have updated with the libraries needed : library("RCurl")
library("RJSONIO"), but I still get the first one to work, and the remaining don't work.

Comment: @DominicComtois, have updated with the libraries needed. library("RCurl")
library("RJSONIO"). The first one works, the other two don't

Comment: Just inserting a few line breaks in your long list of strings does the trick for me (using RStudio).

Comment: @DominicComtois, sorry, insert line breaks? You mean '\n'. I'm sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: No, I mean just break the long lines into several lines (2 or 3 lines instead of only 1 long line)

Comment: @DominicComtois :) works. How does this work?
But thanks to your reply, I realized that it's not a syntax error, so ran it as a script, instead of copy pasting on the terminal and it works.

Would you want to add your reply as an answer?

Comment: @IAMTubby Have you tried by saving it in a .R file and then `source(yourfile.R)` (which will be easier when the file is big) It worked for me. `str(req)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that having very long lines causes problems with the interpreter. I couldn't say exactly why and what is the limit, but breaking the lines into several lines solves the problem:

```
req <- list(
        Inputs = list(
          "input1" = list(
             "ColumnNames" = list("Column 0", "X", "AGE", "FEMALE", "LOS", "NCHRONIC", "RACE", "TOTCHG", "DXCCS_226", "DXCCS_2", "DXCCS_653", "DXCCS_660", "DXCCS_63", "DXCCS_45", "DXCCS_147", "DXCCS_155", "DXCCS_232", 
                                  "DXCCS_205", "DXCCS_237", "DXCCS_254", "DXCCS_108", "DXCCS_97", "DXCCS_145", "DXCCS_159", "DXCCS_161", "DXCCS_127", "DXCCS_211", "DXCCS_250", "DXCCS_55", "DXCCS_138", "DXCCS_153", 
                                  "DXCCS_118", "DXCCS_151", "DXCCS_120", "DXCCS_6", "DXCCS_58", "DXCCS_160", "DXCCS_182", "DXCCS_83", "DXCCS_95", "DXCCS_663", "DXCCS_152", "DXCCS_197", "DXCCS_154", "DXCCS_207", 
                                  "DXCCS_17", "DXCCS_157", "DXCCS_96", "DXCCS_129", "DXCCS_19", "DXCCS_212", "DXCCS_122", "DXCCS_5", "DXCCS_38", "DXCCS_100", "DXCCS_238", "DXCCS_199", "DXCCS_240", "DXCCS_661", 
                                  "DXCCS_99", "DXCCS_242", "DXCCS_149", "DXCCS_135", "DXCCS_114", "DXCCS_42", "DXCCS_59", "DXCCS_109", "DXCCS_184", "DXCCS_189", "DXCCS_27", "DXCCS_103", "DXCCS_140", "DXCCS_44", 
                                  "DXCCS_62", "DXCCS_130", "DXCCS_201", "DXCCS_102", "DXCCS_141", "DXCCS_131", "DXCCS_24", "DXCCS_181", "DXCCS_191", "DXCCS_195", "DXCCS_51", "DXCCS_203", "DXCCS_101", "DXCCS_146", 
                                  "DXCCS_39", "DXCCS_134", "DXCCS_230", "DXCCS_76", "DXCCS_128", "DXCCS_168", "DXCCS_12", "DXCCS_148", "DXCCS_657", "DXCCS_106", "DXCCS_7", "DXCCS_246", "DXCCS_163", "DXCCS_110", 
                                  "DXCCS_50", "DXCCS_111", "DXCCS_116", "DXCCS_28", "DXCCS_233", "DXCCS_243", "DXCCS_175", "DXCCS_126", "DXCCS_81", "DXCCS_21", "DXCCS_209", "DXCCS_137", "DXCCS_204", "DXCCS_259", 
                                  "DXCCS_186", "DXCCS_48", "DXCCS_13", "DXCCS_659", "DXCCS_248", "DXCCS_14", "DXCCS_251", "DXCCS_231", "DXCCS_245", "DXCCS_117", "DXCCS_105", "DXCCS_29", "DXCCS_244", "DXCCS_228", 
                                  "DXCCS_651", "DXCCS_241", "DXCCS_225", "DXCCS_125", "DXCCS_121", "DXCCS_183", "DXCCS_139", "DXCCS_25", "DXCCS_142", "DXCCS_61", "DXCCS_79", "DXCCS_239", "DXCCS_133", "DXCCS_143", 
                                  "DXCCS_158", "DXCCS_136", "DXCCS_252", "DXCCS_193", "DXCCS_144", "DXCCS_85", "DXCCS_123", "DXCCS_170", "DXCCS_229", "DXCCS_654", "DXCCS_172", "DXCCS_46", "DXCCS_115", "DXCCS_32", 
                                  "DXCCS_78", "DXCCS_253", "DXCCS_84", "DXCCS_670", "DXCCS_190", "DXCCS_93", "DXCCS_4", "DXCCS_37", "DXCCS_164", "DXCCS_234", "DXCCS_113", "DXCCS_33", "DXCCS_98", "DXCCS_18", "DXCCS_210",
                                  "DXCCS_35", "DXCCS_112", "DXCCS_202", "DXCCS_64", "DXCCS_658", "DXCCS_196", "DXCCS_11", "DXCCS_60", "DXCCS_1", "DXCCS_15", "DXCCS_119", "DXCCS_26", "DXCCS_235", "DXCCS_162", "DXCCS_236",
                                  "DXCCS_257", "DXCCS_165", "DXCCS_40", "DXCCS_43", "DXCCS_8", "DXCCS_171", "DXCCS_132", "DXCCS_36", "DXCCS_47", "DXCCS_198", "DXCCS_187", "DXCCS_249", "DXCCS_41", "DXCCS_80", "DXCCS_650", 
                                  "DXCCS_20", "DXCCS_192", "DXCCS_22", "DXCCS_188", "DXCCS_200", "DXCCS_215", "DXCCS_217", "DXCCS_90", "DXCCS_30", "DXCCS_56", "DXCCS_185", "DXCCS_82", "DXCCS_178", "DXCCS_3", "DXCCS_52", 
                                  "DXCCS_258", "DXCCS_208", "DXCCS_9", "DXCCS_91", "DXCCS_57", "DXCCS_54", "DXCCS_214", "DXCCS_49", "DXCCS_213", "DXCCS_169", "DXCCS_166", "DXCCS_77", "DXCCS_255", "DXCCS_16", "DXCCS_107", 
                                  "DXCCS_104", "DXCCS_180", "DXCCS_177", "DXCCS_88", "DXCCS_216", "DXCCS_227", "DXCCS_167", "DXCCS_94", "DXCCS_156", "DXCCS_34", "DXCCS_652", "DXCCS_124", "DXCCS_655", "DXCCS_92", "DXCCS_224", 
                                  "DXCCS_247", "DXCCS_662", "DXCCS_194", "DXCCS_10", "DXCCS_89", "DXCCS_23", "DXCCS_179", "DXCCS_656", "DXCCS_173", "DXCCS_256", "DXCCS_176", "DXCCS_31", "DXCCS_53", "DXCCS_87", "DXCCS_206", 
                                  "DXCCS_86", "DXCCS_219", "DXCCS_174", "PRCCS_153", "PRCCS_98", "PRCCS_227", "PRCCS_219", "PRCCS_222", "PRCCS_54", "PRCCS_65", "PRCCS_198", "PRCCS_70", "PRCCS_3", "PRCCS_224", "PRCCS_216", 
                                  "PRCCS_174", "PRCCS_63", "PRCCS_89", "PRCCS_221", "PRCCS_102", "PRCCS_112", "PRCCS_228", "PRCCS_160", "PRCCS_169", "PRCCS_39", "PRCCS_61", "PRCCS_88", "PRCCS_76", "PRCCS_101", "PRCCS_137",
                                  "PRCCS_168", "PRCCS_4", "PRCCS_83", "PRCCS_43", "PRCCS_223", "PRCCS_34", "PRCCS_7", "PRCCS_172", "PRCCS_142", "PRCCS_161", "PRCCS_159", "PRCCS_155", "PRCCS_57", "PRCCS_45", "PRCCS_58", 
                                  "PRCCS_37", "PRCCS_134", "PRCCS_96", "PRCCS_69", "PRCCS_105", "PRCCS_162", "PRCCS_121", "PRCCS_133", "PRCCS_5", "PRCCS_94", "PRCCS_191", "PRCCS_64", "PRCCS_213", "PRCCS_66", "PRCCS_42", 
                                  "PRCCS_95", "PRCCS_146", "PRCCS_47", "PRCCS_78"),
              "Values" = list("Column 0", "X", "AGE", "FEMALE", "LOS", "NCHRONIC", "RACE", "TOTCHG", "DXCCS_226", "DXCCS_2", "DXCCS_653", "DXCCS_660", "DXCCS_63", "DXCCS_45", "DXCCS_147", "DXCCS_155", "DXCCS_232",
                              "DXCCS_205", "DXCCS_237", "DXCCS_254", "DXCCS_108", "DXCCS_97", "DXCCS_145", "DXCCS_159", "DXCCS_161", "DXCCS_127", "DXCCS_211", "DXCCS_250", "DXCCS_55", "DXCCS_138", "DXCCS_153", 
                              "DXCCS_118", "DXCCS_151", "DXCCS_120", "DXCCS_6", "DXCCS_58", "DXCCS_160", "DXCCS_182", "DXCCS_83", "DXCCS_95", "DXCCS_663", "DXCCS_152", "DXCCS_197", "DXCCS_154", "DXCCS_207", 
                              "DXCCS_17", "DXCCS_157", "DXCCS_96", "DXCCS_129", "DXCCS_19", "DXCCS_212", "DXCCS_122", "DXCCS_5", "DXCCS_38", "DXCCS_100", "DXCCS_238", "DXCCS_199", "DXCCS_240", "DXCCS_661", 
                              "DXCCS_99", "DXCCS_242", "DXCCS_149", "DXCCS_135", "DXCCS_114", "DXCCS_42", "DXCCS_59", "DXCCS_109", "DXCCS_184", "DXCCS_189", "DXCCS_27", "DXCCS_103", "DXCCS_140", "DXCCS_44", 
                              "DXCCS_62", "DXCCS_130", "DXCCS_201", "DXCCS_102", "DXCCS_141", "DXCCS_131", "DXCCS_24", "DXCCS_181", "DXCCS_191", "DXCCS_195", "DXCCS_51", "DXCCS_203", "DXCCS_101", "DXCCS_146", 
                              "DXCCS_39", "DXCCS_134", "DXCCS_230", "DXCCS_76", "DXCCS_128", "DXCCS_168", "DXCCS_12", "DXCCS_148", "DXCCS_657", "DXCCS_106", "DXCCS_7", "DXCCS_246", "DXCCS_163", "DXCCS_110", 
                              "DXCCS_50", "DXCCS_111", "DXCCS_116", "DXCCS_28", "DXCCS_233", "DXCCS_243", "DXCCS_175", "DXCCS_126", "DXCCS_81", "DXCCS_21", "DXCCS_209", "DXCCS_137", "DXCCS_204", "DXCCS_259", 
                              "DXCCS_186", "DXCCS_48", "DXCCS_13", "DXCCS_659", "DXCCS_248", "DXCCS_14", "DXCCS_251", "DXCCS_231", "DXCCS_245", "DXCCS_117", "DXCCS_105", "DXCCS_29", "DXCCS_244", "DXCCS_228", 
                              "DXCCS_651", "DXCCS_241", "DXCCS_225", "DXCCS_125", "DXCCS_121", "DXCCS_183", "DXCCS_139", "DXCCS_25", "DXCCS_142", "DXCCS_61", "DXCCS_79", "DXCCS_239", "DXCCS_133", "DXCCS_143", 
                              "DXCCS_158", "DXCCS_136", "DXCCS_252", "DXCCS_193", "DXCCS_144", "DXCCS_85", "DXCCS_123", "DXCCS_170", "DXCCS_229", "DXCCS_654", "DXCCS_172", "DXCCS_46", "DXCCS_115", "DXCCS_32", 
                              "DXCCS_78", "DXCCS_253", "DXCCS_84", "DXCCS_670", "DXCCS_190", "DXCCS_93", "DXCCS_4", "DXCCS_37", "DXCCS_164", "DXCCS_234", "DXCCS_113", "DXCCS_33", "DXCCS_98", "DXCCS_18", "DXCCS_210", 
                              "DXCCS_35", "DXCCS_112", "DXCCS_202", "DXCCS_64", "DXCCS_658", "DXCCS_196", "DXCCS_11", "DXCCS_60", "DXCCS_1", "DXCCS_15", "DXCCS_119", "DXCCS_26", "DXCCS_235", "DXCCS_162", "DXCCS_236",
                              "DXCCS_257", "DXCCS_165", "DXCCS_40", "DXCCS_43", "DXCCS_8", "DXCCS_171", "DXCCS_132", "DXCCS_36", "DXCCS_47", "DXCCS_198", "DXCCS_187", "DXCCS_249", "DXCCS_41", "DXCCS_80", "DXCCS_650",
                              "DXCCS_20", "DXCCS_192", "DXCCS_22", "DXCCS_188", "DXCCS_200", "DXCCS_215", "DXCCS_217", "DXCCS_90", "DXCCS_30", "DXCCS_56", "DXCCS_185", "DXCCS_82", "DXCCS_178", "DXCCS_3", "DXCCS_52", 
                              "DXCCS_258", "DXCCS_208", "DXCCS_9", "DXCCS_91", "DXCCS_57", "DXCCS_54", "DXCCS_214", "DXCCS_49", "DXCCS_213", "DXCCS_169", "DXCCS_166", "DXCCS_77", "DXCCS_255", "DXCCS_16", "DXCCS_107",
                              "DXCCS_104", "DXCCS_180", "DXCCS_177", "DXCCS_88", "DXCCS_216", "DXCCS_227", "DXCCS_167", "DXCCS_94", "DXCCS_156", "DXCCS_34", "DXCCS_652", "DXCCS_124", "DXCCS_655", "DXCCS_92",
                              "DXCCS_224", "DXCCS_247", "DXCCS_662", "DXCCS_194", "DXCCS_10", "DXCCS_89", "DXCCS_23", "DXCCS_179", "DXCCS_656", "DXCCS_173", "DXCCS_256", "DXCCS_176", "DXCCS_31", "DXCCS_53", 
                              "DXCCS_87", "DXCCS_206", "DXCCS_86", "DXCCS_219", "DXCCS_174", "PRCCS_153", "PRCCS_98", "PRCCS_227", "PRCCS_219", "PRCCS_222", "PRCCS_54", "PRCCS_65", "PRCCS_198", "PRCCS_70", 
                              "PRCCS_3", "PRCCS_224", "PRCCS_216", "PRCCS_174", "PRCCS_63", "PRCCS_89", "PRCCS_221", "PRCCS_102", "PRCCS_112", "PRCCS_228", "PRCCS_160", "PRCCS_169", "PRCCS_39", "PRCCS_61", 
                              "PRCCS_88", "PRCCS_76", "PRCCS_101", "PRCCS_137", "PRCCS_168", "PRCCS_4", "PRCCS_83", "PRCCS_43", "PRCCS_223", "PRCCS_34", "PRCCS_7", "PRCCS_172", "PRCCS_142", "PRCCS_161",
                              "PRCCS_159", "PRCCS_155", "PRCCS_57", "PRCCS_45", "PRCCS_58", "PRCCS_37", "PRCCS_134", "PRCCS_96", "PRCCS_69", "PRCCS_105", "PRCCS_162", "PRCCS_121", "PRCCS_133", "PRCCS_5", 
                              "PRCCS_94", "PRCCS_191", "PRCCS_64", "PRCCS_213", "PRCCS_66", "PRCCS_42", "PRCCS_95", "PRCCS_146", "PRCCS_47", "PRCCS_78")
                            )                
                      ),
        GlobalParameters = fromJSON('{}')
        )
```